# What is the difference between python-xlib, python3-xlib, pyxlib and xlib in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, xlib

I individually installed (and posterior uninstalled):

- python-xlib
- python3-xlib
- pyxlib
- xlib

via `pip (un)install` and could execute

```
from Xlib import X, display, Xutil
from Xlib.ext import randr
d = display.Display()
```

with all of them with **Python 3.8.10**. – What is the difference between them? Pip definitively downloads and installs different packages with different sizes.

Comment: Does the documentation on each package shed any light on the differences? I’d *presume* the difference in `python-xlib` and `python3-xlib` is the supporting version of Python; 2.x and 3.x respectively.

Comment: @S3DEV On the first view, it seems to be the same documentation.

Comment: @S3DEV Both run on python3.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've found after a little digging around.

Short answer:
**Use `python-xlib`** as it's [currently maintained](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/#history), whereas the others *appear* to be abandoned projects.

---

A bit of context:

- `xlib`: Xlib (also known as libX11) is an X Window System protocol client library **written in the C programming language**, [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib).  However, the [Python version](https://pypi.org/project/xlib/#description) appears to be [no longer maintained](https://pypi.org/project/xlib/#history).
- `python-xlib`: The Python X Library is intended to be a fully functional X client library for Python programs. It is **written entirely in Python**, in contrast to earlier X libraries for Python (the ancient X extension and the newer plxlib) which were interfaces to the C Xlib. [Ref](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/#description)
- `pyxlib`: Appears to be [no longer maintained](https://pypi.org/project/pyxlib/#history).
- `python3-xlib`: Appears to be [no longer maintained](https://pypi.org/project/python3-xlib/#history).

Answer (score 1):

Use only

- **python-xlib**

The other three

- python3-xlib
- pyxlib
- xlib

are (seemingly) from two individuals (one holds pyxlib and xlib the other holds python3-xlib) with either broken homepage links or pointing to python-xlib. Nothing in python-xlib points to pyxlib or python3-xlib.

In the best case these are just outdated snapshots of python-xlib with questionable changes turned into packages.